# wpf dynamic data display ChartPlotter.AddLineChart function different in new build

Tags: wpf, dynamic-data-display

Dynamic Data Display wpf: the function call

`ChartPlotter.AddLineChart()`

now takes an object parameter as input in the new build 0.4. Has anyone here experienced the same thing? Are there any examples on the web for this? I changed from version 0.3 to this one because of the ColumnChart functionality... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: In this build everything is just different. I dont know what am I missing here. the function just does not work it does not take in the arguments which it would normally take. it seems that this update is totally different.

Comment: Here is the code that worked for 0.3:this.GMPLMSScanPlotter.AddLineGraph(compositeDataSource2,
              new Pen(Brushes.Green, 2),
              new TrianglePointMarker
              {
                  Size = 10.0,
                  Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2.0),
                  Fill = Brushes.GreenYellow
              },
              new PenDescription("Number bugs closed")); but does not work any more as the argument that is expected is an object!???

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a while. I figured that the new build hosted [here](https://d3future.codeplex.com/)has somewhat extended functionality. Among other things, the plots can be added by Plotter.Children.Add(LineGraph) function instead of Plotter.AddLineChart(...) like in original 2009 build.